# I can log in successfully with ssh sert, even if I do not provide passphrase

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, gnome, passphrase

My client OS is Ubuntu 18.04, server is Ubuntu 16.04. I created and uploaded new ssh certs, created ssh config. Cert has passphrase. When I try to log in via ssh in terminal, there appears Gnome prompt with "Enter password to unlock the key". If I press Cancel button, I see "sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation" message in terminal followed with successful login, that is, I am in remote server.

Is it normal? I did not entered my passphrase to any Gnome app.

Comment: Could you show the `ssh -v -v` log of the connection?

Comment: `ssh -v -v` gives `usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
`

Comment: Yeah, you're supposed to add it to your regular ssh command...

Comment: Can you please, explain more detailed what should I do, I am not ssh tech.